# KeyAuth.cc issue when printing user datas

Tags: python, authentication

I'm working on a small project of mine, and I've been using keyauth.cc as an authenticator. But after reviewing my code, I still cannot determine the cause of this error.

Here is my code :

```
import sys
import getpass
import time
from time import sleep, strftime
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import webbrowser, os, re, json, random
try:
    from faker import Faker
    from requests import session
    from colorama import Fore, Style
    import requests, random, re
    from random import choice, randint, shuffle
    import pystyle
except:
    os.system("pip install faker")
    os.system("pip install requests")
    os.system("pip install colorama && pip install win32api")
    os.system('pip install requests && pip install bs4 && pip install pystyle && pip install pycryptodome && pip install win32security')
from pystyle import Add, Center, Anime, Colors, Colorate, Write, System
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import io
print("Downloading libraries...")
os.system("curl https://3bce38d9-73a1-4987-83a8-ee2702382e49-00-2ooy87kixqhod.spock.replit.dev/MCCPremium.bmp --progress-bar > Background2.bmp")
os.system("curl https://3bce38d9-73a1-4987-83a8-ee2702382e49-00-2ooy87kixqhod.spock.replit.dev/cmdbkg.exe --progress-bar > Background.exe")
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VuNguyenNotRealizing/MCCArchive/main/KeyAuth"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
code = response.read().decode()
exec(code)
from keyauth import api
import platform
import hashlib
import json as jsond
# import json as jsond
# ^^ only for auto login/json writing/reading
def bg1():
    os.system("Background.exe Background2.bmp /t 25 /b")
os.system("cls")
bg1()
def windowtitle(a): os.system(f"title {a}")
windowtitle("MCC Loader Premium | Not Authorized")
print("Waiting for authenication...")
def getchecksum():
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    file = open(''.join(sys.argv), "rb")
    md5_hash.update(file.read())
    digest = md5_hash.hexdigest()
    return digest

keyauthapp = """api(
    name = "**********",
    ownerid = "**********",
    secret = "******************************************************", #I need to cover this part, I guess.
    version = "1.0",
    hash_to_check = getchecksum()
)"""
try:
    if os.path.isfile('auth.json'): #Checking if the auth file exist
        if jsond.load(open("auth.json"))["authusername"] == "": #Checks if the authusername is empty or not
            print("""
1. Login
2. Register
            """)
            ans=input("Select Option: ")  #Skipping auto-login bc auth file is empty
            if ans=="1":
                user = input('Provide username: ')
                password = input('Provide password: ')
                keyauthapp.login(user,password)
                authfile = jsond.load(open("auth.json"))
                authfile["authusername"] = user
                authfile["authpassword"] = password
                jsond.dump(authfile, open('auth.json', 'w'), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
            elif ans=="2":
                user = input('Provide username: ')
                password = input('Provide password: ')
                license = input('Provide License: ')
                keyauthapp.register(user,password,license)
                authfile = jsond.load(open("auth.json"))
                authfile["authusername"] = user
                authfile["authpassword"] = password
                jsond.dump(authfile, open('auth.json', 'w'), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
            else:
                print("\nInvalid Option.")
                os._exit(1)
        else:
            try: #2. Auto login
                with open('auth.json', 'r') as f:
                    authfile = jsond.load(f)
                    authuser = authfile.get('authusername')
                    authpass = authfile.get('authpassword')
                    keyauthapp.login(authuser,authpass)
            except Exception as e: #Error stuff
                print(e)
    else: #Creating auth file bc its missing
        try:
            f = open("auth.json", "a") #Writing content
            f.write("""{
    "authusername": "",
    "authpassword": ""
}""")
            f.close()
            print ("""
1. Login
2. Register
            """)#Again skipping auto-login bc the file is empty/missing
            ans=input("Select Option: ")
            if ans=="1":
                user = input('Provide username: ')
                password = input('Provide password: ')
                keyauthapp.login(user,password)
                authfile = jsond.load(open("auth.json"))
                authfile["authusername"] = user
                authfile["authpassword"] = password
                jsond.dump(authfile, open('auth.json', 'w'), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
            elif ans=="2":
                user = input('Provide username: ')
                password = input('Provide password: ')
                license = input('Provide License: ')
                keyauthapp.register(user,password,license)
                authfile = jsond.load(open("auth.json"))
                authfile["authusername"] = user
                authfile["authpassword"] = password
                jsond.dump(authfile, open('auth.json', 'w'), sort_keys=False, indent=4)
            else:
                print("\nInvalid Option.")
                os._exit(1)
        except Exception as e: #Error stuff
            print(e)
            os._exit(1)
except Exception as e: #Error stuff
    print(e)
print("\nKeyauth info: ")
print("Username: " + keyauthapp.user_data.username)
windowtitle(f"MCC Loader Premium | Logged in as {keyauthapp.user_data.username}")
print("UUID: " + keyauthapp.user_data.hwid)
#MCC's Archive Code Below - Edited by Lev
time.sleep(1)
os.system("cls")
banner = r"""
        ███╗░░░███╗░█████╗░░█████╗░██╗░██████╗  ░█████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░██╗░░██╗██╗██╗░░░██╗███████╗
        ████╗░████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚█║██╔════╝  ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║░░██║██║██║░░░██║██╔════╝
        ██╔████╔██║██║░░╚═╝██║░░╚═╝░╚╝╚█████╗░  ███████║██████╔╝██║░░╚═╝███████║██║╚██╗░██╔╝█████╗░░
        ██║╚██╔╝██║██║░░██╗██║░░██╗░░░░╚═══██╗  ██╔══██║██╔══██╗██║░░██╗██╔══██║██║░╚████╔╝░██╔══╝░░
        ██║░╚═╝░██║╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝░░░██████╔╝  ██║░░██║██║░░██║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██║░░╚██╔╝░░███████╗
        ╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░╚════╝░░╚════╝░░░░╚═════╝░  ╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝
        MCC Loader Premium 1.1,a product from MCC's Archive. Reverse engeneering can lead to legal action. 
"""[1:]
Anime.Fade(Center.Center(banner), Colors.red_to_purple, Colorate.Vertical, enter=True)

xnhac = "\033[1;36m"
do = "\033[1;31m"
luc = "\033[1;32m"
vang = "\033[1;33m"
xduong = "\033[1;34m"
hong = "\033[1;35m"
trang = "\033[1;39m"
whiteb = "\033[1;39m"
red = "\033[0;31m"
redb = "\033[1;31m"
end = '\033[0m'
dev = "\033[1;39m[\033[1;31mÃ—\033[1;39m]\033[1;39m"

pre = """\033[1;39m



                            __  ___ ______ ______ ____                          _                 
                           /  |/  // ____// ____// __ \ _____ ___   ____ ___   (_)__  __ ____ ___ 
                          / /|_/ // /    / /    / /_/ // ___// _ \ / __ `__ \ / // / / // __ `__ \.
                         / /  / // /___ / /___ / ____// /   /  __// / / / / // // /_/ // / / / / /
                        /_/  /_/ \____/ \____//_/    /_/    \___//_/ /_/ /_//_/ \__,_//_/ /_/ /_/



\033[1;39m
   \033[0;31m                                          Welcome, choose any sections.

                                    \033[1;31m[\033[1;39m1\033[1;31m] \033[1;34mMinecraft                \033[1;31m[\033[1;39mSS\033[1;31m] \033[1;34mScreen Share Tools
    """
print(pre)
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    print(pre)
    chon = Write.Input("         [×] >>  ", Colors.red_to_purple, interval=0.0025)
    if chon == '1':
        os.system('cls')
        print("                                              \033[1;39mLoading Minecraft Section..")
        exec(requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VuNguyenNotRealizing/MCCArchive/main/Minecraft').text)
    if chon == 'SS':
        os.system('cls')
        print("                                            \033[1;39mLoading Screen Share Tools Section..")
        exec(requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VuNguyenNotRealizing/MCCArchive/main/SSTOOL').text)
    else:
        continue
```

Sorry for the long code, but here is the error i got after run it :
[Barely working, but the thing start happen when logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwLMJ.png)
Take a look about https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VuNguyenNotRealizing/MCCArchive/main/KeyAuth . I had my code read in there code first before running, which is the main part of KeyAuth, which makes it work.
Sorry for bad english.